# Why the browser still pull the resource from the server?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, caching, browser-cache

I have ASP.NET web application with my custom HttpModule. This module checks whether browser requested `module.js`. If so, it returns generated javascript file with the following header:

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=600
Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 11 Feb 2012 03:15:00 GMT
Expires:Sat, 11 Feb 2012 03:25:00 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

So the `module.js` should be cached for 10 minutes. But once I refresh the page - I receive newly generated javascript file (but not the cached by the browser). Why it is so?

Btw, I've disabled output caching in `web.config`, because I don't want it to be cached on the server, I want it to be cached in browser:

```
<modules>
          <remove name="OutputCache" />
```

Here is my module code:

```
public class JSModule: IHttpModule
{
    public CSSModule()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(OnBeginRequest);

    }

    private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication context = (HttpApplication)sender;
        if (context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Contains("module.js"))
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";

            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
            context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10));
            context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0));

            context.Response.Write(string.Format("console.log({0});", (int)context.Application["counter"]));
            context.Application["counter"] = (int)context.Application["counter"] + 1;
            context.Response.Flush();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

And here is my page HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>    
</head>
<body>   
    <script src="module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So each time I refresh page I see incrementing numbers in my console in Chrome. But I'd like to see the number to be changed only each 10 minutes. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "Refresh" a page, the browser will request every resource, regardless of its cache status. If you want to test if your caching is working, you should simply click a link or select the address in the address bar and press [ENTER]; don't use 'refresh'.